# How to add word "appendix" before "table"?

Tags: tables, appendix

For my appendix tables, I am using:

```
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A.\arabic{table}}
```

This ensures the expression "Table A.1" appears on top of the first appendix table. However, I would it to say "Appendix Table A.1". How can I do this?

Comment: You could redefine \tablename to include \appendixname: `\edef\tablename{\appendixname~\tablename}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `etoolbox` package, use the commands

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{subappendices}{\renewcommand{\tablename}{}
    \renewcommand{\thetable}{\textbf{Appendix Table \arabic{table}}}
                                }
```